# Rails 3 ActiveMerchant credit card not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I cannot seem to get the card validating at all. Please help me!

The error I get when submitting a blank order form.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in OrdersController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: card_number, card_verification
```

in order.rb

```
  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification
  attr_accessible :card_expires_on, :card_type, :cart_id, :first_name, :ip_address, :last_name
  belongs_to :cart

  validate :validate_card, :on => :create
  validate :validate_card, :on => :update
```

I obviously do not want to store card_number and card_verification in the database.

The methods in order.rb

```
  def validate_card
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each {|msg| errors[:base] << msg} if credit_card.invalid?

    end

    def credit_card
        @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
            :type                       => card_type,
            :number             => card_number,
            :verification_value => card_verification,
            :month                  => card_expires_on.try(:month),
            :year                       => card_expires_on.try(:year),
            :first_name         => first_name,
            :last_name          => last_name
            )
    end
```

Please try and help!

If this helps I have this in the Gemfile

```
gem 'activemerchant'
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: card_number, card_verification

Add these attributes (`:card_number`, `:card_verification`) to `attr_accessible` list. Validation didn't even kick in yet, it's ActiveRecord trying to create your object from `params`.

Comment: Thanks. Now it doesn't validate anything and it accepts anything to be passed as a credit card number for the validation to pass.

Ahh, please help! :(